# Nunit: global setup method for running every tests in assembly

Tags: nunit

In Nunit we have `Setup` method that runs before every test in a `TestFixture` class. And we have `OneTimeSetup` that runs before all tests in an assembly.

But what I want is an attribute that I specify only once on a method, that will get the method to run on all tests inside an assembly. This is so that I don't have to specify the Setup method for each test class.

Is there such an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by deriving all your `TestFixture` classes from a common base class and put the `SetUp` method there.